# Looking for a tool for Orthorectification of Archived Air Photos

Tags: open-source-gis

I was wondering if anyone knows of an open source, perferabily something for QGIS and not GRASS, that can be used for orthorectifying scanned archived air photos.  I have looked at OSSIM and a few other packages, but they do not allow (from what I can tell) for a single image to be processed based on user input from a geoimage or vectors.  Packages like ERDAS and PCI allow for this, but I am looking for an open source solution.  The Georefrencer plugin to QGIS is good, but I would like to be able to use a DEM (digital elevation model) as a source for the Z information for terrain relief issues.

Any help would be great, or clarification on OSSIM or other products that I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: What do you mean by "use a DEM in the calculation"?

Comment: What I mean is have a DEM (digital elevation model) as a source for the Z information.  Without the use of a DEM it really isn't an ortho.  Not using a DEM and only using a Polynomial transformation is really just rubbersheeting.  This is possible with the GeoReferencer plugin in QGIS, but it lacks the association to the terrain (DEM) for relief issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [AirPhotoSE](http://www.uni-koeln.de/~al001/airphotose.html) - it's free but not open source - which is part of BASP (The Bonn Archaeological Software Package). It's designed for Windows, but it should work well under Wine on Linux.

I believe the author, Irwin Scollar, is intending to make the full version of AirPhoto open source in the near future, but I've not got any dates for it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to have a look at the GeoRect tool that comes with [FalconView](http://www.falconview.org/trac/FalconView)

Probably windows only, but LGPL.

Comment: Bookmarked that one! +1